# Terraform Import bucket policy from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Is there a way I can use `terraform import aws_s3_bucket` to import an s3 bucket AND it's policy? I'm trying to import my existing s3 buckets into terraform so that I can apply replication configuration and to them. For example:

```
#Importing an existing bucket
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.replication myexistingbucket

#Maybe be able to grab s3 bucket policy from the import
data "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "replication" {
  bucket = myexistingbucket
}

#Terraform configuration to add replication to the existing bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "replication" {
  bucket   = "myexistingbucket"
  policy = data.aws_s3_bucket_policy.replication

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  replication_configuration {
    ####configuration code here
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  } 
}
```

My code looks like what is above without the aws_s3_bucket_policy data block. The issue is when I run this configuration, it applies the replication configuration but it makes the bucket policy blank after the run since I don't define a bucket policy. I'm hoping I don't have to import every single bucket policy (there are multiple buckets that are being imported and each has a very long policy).

Comment: Why is the policy length relevant for importing? I would try defining `aws_s3_bucket_policy` resource and importing the policy explicitly via `terraform import`

Comment: You have to manually fill the policies out for correct import.